# Crud genérico com phpoo e pdo (sem framework)

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Quero fazer uma espécie de Crud Genérico e implementei a função de insert, sei que do jeito que fiz não é melhor maneira de se fazer e não quero usar nenhum tipo de frameworks e por isso gostaria de ajuda, dicas.

O que mais está me causando confusão é como vou fazer um correto e eficiente tratamento dos dados antes de serem inseridos/editados, eu fiz uma função de limpeza mas sei que está mais para uma "gambiarra", porque gosto de usar os filters sanitize do php e não estou achando uma forma de usá-los muito bem com orientação a objetos e de forma genérica.

Vi que tem alguns tópicos semelhantes ao meu, mas não encontrei o que procuro.

**Classe alunos:**

```
<?php
require_once 'crud.php';
require_once 'usuarios.php';
require_once 'conexao.php';

class Alunos extends Usuarios {

    private $matricula;
    private $curso;
    private $turma;
    private $dados_cadastrais;
    private $con;

    //Métodos
    public function cadastrarAluno($dados) {
        $verifica = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email");
        $verifica->bindValue(":email", $dados['email']);
        $verifica->execute();

        if ($verifica->rowCount() > 0) {
           return false;
        } else {
            $this->dados_cadastrais = $this->limpeza($dados);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, nomepai, nomemae, datanasc, naturalidade, nacionalidade, estadocivil, sexo, endereco, complemento, bairro, cidade, estado, cep, telefone, celular, celular2, email, cpf, rg, orgaoe, estadoe, datae, formacao, cursof, senha, nivel) values (:nome, :nomepai, :nomemae, :datanasc, :naturalidade, :nacionalidade, :estadocivil, :sexo, :endereco, :complemento, :bairro, :cidade, :estado, :cep, :telefone, :celular, :celular2, :email, :cpf, :rg, :orgaoe, :estadoe, :datae, :formacao, :cursof, :senha, :nivel)";

            $cadastro = new Crud();
            if($cadastro->cadastrar($sql, $this->dados_cadastrais)){
                 return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function limpeza($dados){
        foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
            if(($key == "cpf") || ($key == "rg")){
                $_POST[$key] = filter_var($this->limpaDoc($valor), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }else if(($key == "data") || ($key == "datae") || ($key == "datanasc")){
                 $_POST[$key] = filter_var($this->formataDataEua($valor), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }else if(($key == "senha")){
                 $_POST[$key] = filter_var(md5($valor), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }else{
                $_POST[$key] = filter_var($valor, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }    
        }

        return $dados;
    }

    function formataDataEua($data){
        $data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data)));
        return $data;
    }

    function limpaDoc($valor) {
        $valor = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $valor);
        return $valor;
    }

    //Métodos especiais
    function __construct() {
        $this->nivel = 0;
        $this->con = new Conexao();
    }
```

**Classe Crud**

```
<?php
require_once 'conexao.php';
class Crud {

    private $con;
    private $insert;
    private $update;
    private $delete;

    //Métodos especiais
    function __construct() {
        $this->con = new Conexao();
    }

    function insert($sql, $dados) {
        $this->insert = $this->con->conectar()->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
            if(is_numeric($valor)){
                $this->insert->bindValue(":$key", $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }else{
                $this->insert->bindValue(":$key", $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }
        if ($this->insert->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Bom, este código todo é bem gambiarra, então nem posso ajudar muito, de acordo com o que pede na pergunta a solução seria começar fazer tudo de novo. Vou dar o conselho que sempre dou e que sempre ignoram. Comece pelo básico, prenda fazer o fundamental bem para depois pensar em OOP. Quem sabe descubra que OOP não é tudo isto, existe mais um marketing em cima disso do que uma solução real. Até é uma solução para problemas quem pedem OOP, feito por quem domina muito bem. A maioria dos códigos OOP que eu vejo ficariam muito melhor sem ser OOP. Até porque eles nem são OOP de verdade. Este caso.

Comment: Da forma que está, eu faria a verificação dos dados antes de consultar o email, caso contrário sempre haverá uma consulta. Em segundo, a consulta do email - se está cadastrado ou não - também faz parte do C**R**UD, não vi sentido separar como fez.

Comment: Se seu problema é validação, não precisa de um framework para isso, basta ter uma lib que você possa implementar. O Laravel tem uma validação interessante na minha opinião, e você pode tomar como base.